# Public Folder Auto Replies only go to internal users

Tags: windows-server-2003, exchange-2003, email-server, public-folders

I am currently running windows 2003 RC2, with Exchange 2003

I've setup a public folder, and it can receive internal and external mails with no problem.

I've used the folder assistant to create a reply template, one that I wish to fire for every message it receives.
When I test an internal message, (via outlook) it's delivered to the public folder, and the reply template is recieved with no problem.
When I test an external message, (via Gmail) it's delivered to the public folder, and the reply template is not triggered.

Any ideas as to why this may be happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Automatic replies to the internet (including Out of Office) are off by default in Exch 2003. I think this setting applies to your situation too. To enable them, [try this](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/266166).

Comment: Thanks for the tip - I am unsure that it works as of yet, (I have 100% confidence that it will, as I think I forgot that step!) - but you did answer the question, which is all I wanted! Thanks a lot :)